# What exacty is io_context?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have been going throught the boost asio library in which most of the objects need the io_context object as argument to the constructor. I have read what io_context object,according to the documentation it states that it is

> **The io_context class provides the core I/O functionality for users of the asynchronous I/O objects**

Which confuses me because isn't that what **iostream** does.I'm really sure i'm missing something,please help me clarify it and also i don't see much difference between **I/O objects** with the **sockets** other than fact that sockets can be used for exchanging data between two devices whereas I/O objects enable us to exchange data with our computer.I'm really confused at this point!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`io_context`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html) contains the state required to run the [event-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) in the thread using platform-specific calls, such as [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [`epoll`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html). Normally, there can be one (active) event loop per thread.

This component runs the event-loop invoking low-level platform-specific calls to acquire operating-system events such as socket readiness, timer, signal, idle and deliver them to user-registered callbacks in portable fashion.

It doesn't do any I/O, rather it invokes the callbacks when I/O can be done, e.g. network data has arrived and the socket is ready for read. The callbacks are expected to do their processing/non-blocking-I/O promptly and return in order to not block the event-loop in the thread.

Such a component is sometimes called an *operating-system event demultiplexer* because calls like `select` and `epoll` report file descriptor readiness, timeout and signal events by returning different values, which must be examined first (along with `errno` for signals) to distinguish what events it has reported. This examination of the return value to detect the event type followed by calling the corresponding event handler is *demultiplexing* of different event types reported by one syscall. These syscalls block the calling thread (to avoid burning CPU cycles / draining batteries) until one of these events happens, and that's why the caller has to *demultiplex* the return value to tell what kind of event is reported.

See [Basic Boost.Asio Anatomy](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/basics.html) for more details.

Other popular event loops are [`libevent`](https://libevent.org/) and [`libuv`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv)

[The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) is old but quite instructive on the subject of async I/O.

---

[C++20 coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) introduce a new programming model, which has benefits of being simpler to write and read and it mitigates *callback hell* inherent in non-blocking I/O code. See full details in [Boost.Asio supports coroutines](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio-coroutines).

Async/coroutines I/O model is cheaper/easier to code for. It is still the same event-loop invoking the callbacks underneath, but now these callbacks do the coroutine state create/save/load/destroy to implement the async programming model for the user.

Comment: Can each process have only 1 io_context ? Is it possible to have multiple threads in a process and each thread running an io_context ?

Comment: @HariniSj https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Sorry, I have carefully read the document which is linked to, but I am still not so sure. As per the document, which says that:“In general, it is safe to make concurrent use of distinct objects.” So, it seems that there could be more than one io_context in a single process. More is at the next comment.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I am confused again after I have read another document. As per this [document](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html), which says that:The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until this operation completes. It seems that two boost::ansy_write could not be could be called at the same time, so it seeems that it's useless to have more than one io_context in a single process.

Comment: The link given in `See Basic Boost.Asio Anatomy for more details.` is broken. This is the correct link now: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html (Edit queue is full, so can't edit the post)